# Problems running Britannica 2013 in OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, applications, software, java

I recently installed the Encyclopædia Britannica 2013 Ultimate DVD in my Mac running OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion. In the box is stated that only 10.6 - 10.7 versions are supported, and indeed I've run into a couple of problems: both the "Timelines" and "A-Z Quick Search" windows display a blank screen.

I contacted technical support and the only answer I received was that OS X 10.8 is not a supported version, and they don't seem to be planning a patch to fix the issue. To the best of my knowledge, I'm on my own. It appears to me that the problem is related to the Java version in use, given that Britannica's application is written in that language. Maybe someone has faced the same problem and can suggest a workaround? for the record: I'm using JDK 1.7.0_13-b20

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't trust Oracle JDK at all. I use [JDK](http://connect.apple.com) from Apple. Can you try it?